# Twilio : forwarding +1 tollfree number to local number in other country.

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am trying to forward a +1 toll-free number to +372 number.

So when I call from +1844 it says, "it is not toll-free number and caller has to pay" but when I call from +91 (india), it doesn't say any message.

Is there any parameter I need to pass to  to avoid this message?

Thanks,

Comment: You mean you are calling the +1 toll free number from another toll-free number? Thats not very clear to me. When you say you call the +1 number from India, no message, does the call connect? Can you share more details about how are you forwarding? Is it basic twiml call forwarding?

Comment: Yeah. It is basic twiml forwarding. We have +1 toll free number. And I tried calling from Indian number it doesn't play message. But when a client from +372 calls, it plays messages even before ringing.
So I came to know that toll free numbers are meant to be used in country only. If you call toll free number from outside, you will be charged for international call.